# The Ajax request does not return an answer from the server

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a code in JS like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $("body").data("url") + "/Documents/CheckDoc",
    data: {
        docID: id
    },
    dataType: 'text',

}).success(function (json) {
    if (json.status) {
        if (json.result) { // word template format
            window.open($("body").data("url") + '/Case/OpenEnforcementDocument?DocID=' + id + '&RRcode=' + RR);

        }
        else { //html template format
            window.open($("body").data("url") + '/EnforcementPrintout/Printout?DocID=' + id + '&copys=' + copys, "_blank");
        }
    }
    else {
        toastr.error(json.message);
    }

});
toastr.error("error");
```

It refers to the CheckDoc function on the server
And there it works great but when it comes back to JavaScript
It does not return to .success and does not reach the last row of the function: toastr.error
Which had to be carried out anyway
It is as if flying from this function and not returning to it again

Someone might know what the problem might be
Will help me a lot

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's look like there is some mistake in your code, you closed your code after  `dataType: 'text',` by `})`  , please try this and let us know:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $("body").data("url") + "/Documents/CheckDoc",
    data: { docID: id },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (json) {
        if (json.status) {
            if (json.result) { // word template format
                window.open($("body").data("url") + '/Case/OpenEnforcementDocument?DocID=' + id + '&RRcode=' + RR);

            }
            else { //html template format
                window.open($("body").data("url") + '/EnforcementPrintout/Printout?DocID=' + id + '&copys=' + copys, "_blank");
            }
        }
        else {
            toastr.error(json.message);
        }

    },

    failure: function (response) {
        alert("failure");
    },
    error: function (xhr, ex) {
        alert('error')
    }
});
```